# Recurring local notification in iOS - objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a date picker called timePicker that allows the user to select hour and minutes to receive the notification, and on button click I want to schedule notification at that time for the current day if the time has not yet passed, or for the next day if the time has passed. I then want the notification to repeat every day at the exact same time. I have the first part kind of figured out, but I can't get the repeating to work. The code is legacy, and as such is written in objective c. I would greatly appreciate as much of a code example as you are willing to write for me, but any advice at all would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recurring Local Notification in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35601515/recurring-local-notification-in-ios)

Comment: that is written in swift, I do not know swift.

Comment: First of all you didn't show any line of code that you are using currently, secondly it's 1 line of code in Swift as an answer in duplicated question - should be easy to figure out how to do it in Obj-c

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski You should not mark a question as a duplicate if said question is in an entirely different language, even if the languages are closely related. StackOverflow is meant to be referential in nature, so someone searching for this solution in this specific language may find such. Instead finding a closed question with no answer and a link to an answer in another language is not proper for the intended nature of this site.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is what you are likely looking for.

```
UILocalNotification *notification = [UILocalNotification new];
notification.fireDate = /*Alert Date*/;
notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitDay;//Once per day
[notification setAlertBody:@"Your message"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```

Set the repeatInterval to whatever NSCalendarUnit you'd like.

If you need something more custom just make an iterative loop and change the fireDate accordingly each iteration. (Make sure you unschedule them in the next session if needed).

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate the answer.